# Get primitive value from chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

Basically, there is a stored primitive I would like to set as a value of a jQuery UI Tab setting:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    active: chrome.storage.local.get("idx", function(obj){ 
                console.log(obj["idx"])}); // returns primitive integer I want. 
            }), ...  
});
```

The standard chrome-storage-get protocol is quite convoluted and I am unsure how I can simply set the object property value itself to be the value of `active:` rather than the object.

```
active: 3 // chrome.storage.local.get("idx")
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not quite following.  Are you trying to `get` the value of the key `idx`?  Or are you trying to `set` the value of the key `idx` to be the value `active`?

Comment: @Teepeemm I can get the value of the key inside the callback, I simply want to get that value as a primitive instead of returning the object as right now it is active: [object]

Comment: Javascript doesn't have primitives; everything is an object.  I think what you're missing is that `get` doesn't return anything.  Instead, inside the callback `function(obj)`, `obj` has the value that you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.storage` is asynchronous, so your code would look more like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("idx", function(obj) {
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    active: obj.idx  
  });
});
```